# Git cherry pick also introduced a new file - how to get some of the commit?

Tags: git, merge

I merged in a commit using `cherry-pick` from a topic branch as it had some changes that would've been useful on the main branch. Unfortunately, I didn't notice that the commit also introduced a new file started on the topic branch. This means that during the merge I get most of the files staged and ready to add, but a conflict on that one marked with "deleted by us".

I'm not sure of my next move. I'd like to keep the rest of the commit, and then later when the rest of the commits from the topic branch are merged in, the new file and all of its changes come in unhindered. Is this possible?

I see my next moves as:

- `git rm` the file, mark the cherry-pick as ok, and hope that this doesn't delete the file on a merge too.
- merge it in and ignore it (a nice hacky possibility I'm sure most devs would do but not admit to:)
- fail the merge, go back in to the topic branch, revert the commit, recommit without adding in the new file, then remerge back into the main branch. I'm hoping there's an easier way than this.

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest splitting the commit, as described in [this chapter of the Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Splitting-a-Commit).

Answer (score 1):

If you successfully `cherry-pick`ed and lost just that one file, you can do a `checkout` from `HEAD^` and get the file back the way it was most recently:

```
git checkout HEAD^ the/path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the commit you are cherry-picking is sane enough (that is - one single change which cannot be split into smaller changes), the file is needed by changes in other files. Working tree will be in broken state without that file. If during merge you have modified the other code to not use the file, you can as well delete the file during merge.

If the commit can be split into smaller changes, you can try that.